# React adding favorites with checkboxes

Tags: html, reactjs, checkbox, checkboxlist

[Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSHpV.jpg)
[Favourites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD5Ic.png)
im trying to do a website witch react and i use an api to recieve data. The Data i recieved gets put into a list and then i produce a button for every item in this list. Now i also produce a check box for every item in the list, but the production is in a seperate component. what i want to do ist that, if the checkbox of one item gets checked, the item should be stored in a cache and put out again as an button on a seperate page. My Question now is how do i do that?

Thank you in advance.

This is where i produce the checkbox:

```
import React from "react";
export default function Favcheck() {
  
  
  return (
    <>
         <div class="favcheck">
           Favorit
           <input type="checkbox" name="name"  class="checkbox" id="heart" />
          </div>
      
    </>
  );
}
```

this is where the buttons are made:

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as React from "react";
import Favcheck from "./favcheck.jsx";
import Mensapage from "./mensapage.jsx";
import site from "./home.jsx";

export default function Mensbuttons(props) {
  
  return (
    <>
      
      <div class="formcontainer">
        <form method="get" action="/mensapage" id="mensaform">
          <button  type="submit" class="mensabutton" key={props.key}>
            <div class="mensatext">{props.name}</div>
          </button>
          <br></br>
          <Favcheck />
        </form>
      </div>
     
    </>
  );
}
```

and this is where the buttons are used:

```
import  React,{ useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

import Nav from "./nav.jsx";

import Mensbuttons from "./mensbuttons.jsx";


export default function Home(props) {
 
 let site="test";
  
 const[posts,setPosts] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://openmensa.org/api/v2/canteens?near[lat]=52.517037&near[lng]=13.38886&near[dist]=15')
    .then(res =>{
     
      setPosts(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  },[])
   console.log(posts);
  
    
  return (
    <>
    
      <Nav />
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Mensen</h1>
        
      </div>
      {posts.map((list) => {
        return <Mensbuttons name={list.name} key={list.id} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by putting it into a cache and put out again? Maybe some mockup picture would help to understand what do you want achieve.

Comment: oh yeah i wrote that wrong i want to put my favourites into the cache and read them out and i want to remove them from the cache when the checkbox is not checked anymore

Answer (score 0):

here are some mockup pictures
i want to get specific objects to the favourites page by checking the checkbox

[here are the favourites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ughXT.png)
[here are the buttons with checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMNp5.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of adding this info as an answer, could you edit your question to include it?